# How do I put space between my buttons?

Tags: html, css

I have tried to add margin to my buttons but it makes the last button jump down a row. I think I know what is happening here but I'm not positive on how I should fix it. Here is what I have, what should I do?

```css
.button {
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  height: max-content;
  background: white;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px 10px black;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px 10px black;
  box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -1px grey;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 10px;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<a href="/" class="button">Page1</a>
<a href="/" class="button">Page2</a>
<a href="/" class="button">Page3</a>
```

Comment: I recommend using bootstrap v.4 (or version 3, if you cannot use v4), is that an option for you?

Comment: try using shorthand CSS `margin` - all 4 values on one line. It goes clockwise, top, right, bottom, left. Single value is put on all 4 positions. So, in your case use  `margin:12px;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `.button + .button` rule to add a left margin when one button follows another. Like this, for example:

```css
.button {
    width: calc(80% / 3);
    height: max-content;
    background: white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px 10px black;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 8px 6px 10px black;
    box-shadow: 0 8px 6px -1px grey;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
}

.button + .button {
    margin-left: calc(10%);
}
```

```html
<a href="/" class="button">Page1</a>
<a href="/" class="button">Page2</a>
<a href="/" class="button">Page3</a>
```

Here, the three buttons are allocated 80% of the parent containter's width, and the remaining 20% is shared equally between the second and third buttons.

Answer (score -2):

```css
a {
  margin:12px;
}
```

```html
<a href="/" class="button">Page1</a>
<a href="/" class="button">Page2</a>
<a href="/" class="button">Page3</a>
```

Comment: You haven't specified your code to involve the needs of @JamesKin's involve the CSS code from the 'button' class. If you were to add this code if would obviously not work.

Comment: @MaxCollier what does `involve the needs of @JamesKin's involve the CSS code` mean? Is that a typo?

Comment: He has a bunch of rules within his rule set 'button' which you haven't included. For example the width and shadowing effects. Also his design involves spanning the buttons across the top of the content area which yours does not evening though he hasn't specified this.